# TL071 trouble (suspected fake)

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have currently acquired 20pcs of TL071CP for my circuits. I am usually using TL071CN without any problem, but TL071CP doesn't seem to work in exactly same setup. I cannot figure out why. Is it possible the chips are fake (ordered from ebay). Can anyone please help me? Circuit attached.[image]

TL071CP produces NO OUTPUT on output pin in same setup as TL071CN.
[TL071CN](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000488.pdf)
[TL071CP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl071a.pdf)

Comment: 'but TL071CP doesn't seem to work in exactly same setup'. Please describe how it acts differently with the same set up. Also include links to the datasheets for both parts.

Comment: i've updated the question to your requirenements

Comment: So ... is pin 6 at Vcc? at GND or somewhere in between? What voltage is Vcc? What voltage is on the other pins (2, 3, 4)? Can you measure the AC voltage that comes from the mic? Do you see that AC voltage on pin 3? Do have a scope?

Comment: The TL071 is a cheap piece of crap that nobody is going to fake. Seriously! That would be like counterfeiting pennies. But you never know with eBay. Someone could have passed on defective stuff to you. Is the chip socketed in your circuit? Can you easily try all 20?

Comment: Yes, I tried 5 different ICs (yes I have a socket in circuit). TL071CN works fine, TL071CP no signal. Supply voltage is 9V.

Comment: Check datasheet to ENSURE pinout is identical for N & P versions (MUST be but eg N not actually specified [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl071a.pdf). Try higher Vcc - should be OK. "No output" is wrong - tell us what DC voltage Vout is at. Should be Vcc/2 - is it?

Comment: Pinout is exactly the same (I have put links to datasheets in the question). Output pin is at 0V.

Comment: My guess would be they are real, as Kaz pointed out they are cheap. They are US $0.20 in quantity.

Comment: Could you try to take good macro pictures of your parts? Counterfeit parts often have weird markings...

Comment: Had the same problem, cheap TL071CP's from Ebay turned out to bet mislabeled TL072s (or something similar, like TL082?). Thanks for the heads-up, I thought I was going nuts. First real evidence for fake part I have come across, I have had some suspicious L6203 batches though...

Comment: Input capacitor is oriented the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem with 10 of tl071cp purchased on ebay. I changed the output pin with 1 instead of 6 and it works! Probably they are tl072

Comment: whoa, good tip! will try that out. i need some tl072 as well :)

Comment: You need to do more than that. The power supply goes to 4,8 in a dual op-amp, not 4,7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting them in facing correctly (I am assuming socketed) and swapping between the -CP and the -CN >ON THE SAME BOARD<, looking at your schematic, there should be minimal difference. The big difference you get indicates bad part. Get some more and try again.